# Php global variable range?

Tags: php

update:

the code i put below will be invoked by a form on other webpage. so that's why I didn't made a instance of a obj.

More detail code:

```
$serverloc='serverURL';

class Aclass{

           function push(){
             global $serverloc;
             echo $serverloc;
             funNotinClass();
           } 

           function otherFunction(){

              echo $serverloc;

           }
}

funNotinClass(){

      echo $serverloc;
}
```

There is a Class contains 2 functiona "push()" and "otherFunction()" and there is independent function "funNotinClass()" and push() calls it. The class is for a web form in other page. When user click submit the form call the class and use the push() function. A weird thing I found is that the global var $serverloc is invisible to push() and funNotinClass()(they don't print out any thing), but otherFuction() which is a function just like puch() inside of the Aclass can just use the $serverloc(I dont even add global in front of it). How strange....anyone know what is the reason caused this?

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

I read many information about the scope of a global var in php.
they all say a global var is defined outside of function or class and you can use it by using global this key word.

So this is my code

```
$serverloc='serverURL';

class Aclass{

function Afunction(){
 global $serverloc;
 echo $serverloc;

} 
}
```

but when I run this class it didn't print anything out.
Is that because I did something wrong or global var just doesn't work this way. Since all the example I read before are just access a global var in functions directly not a function in a class

Comment: You never instantiated the class or called the method - [`$obj = new Aclass; $obj->Afunction();`](http://codepad.org/POMjdETI). But for the record, global variables are *bad* and usually indicate bad design.

Comment: @DaveRandom +1 that's another spot on comment. You really should be putting these as answers.

Comment: As a general programming rule, the fewer global variables you have, the better. There are times when they're necessary, but most of the time they're bad practice and should be avoided. You'd be better off passing the value into the function (or into the constructor function if you need it throughout the class).

Answer (score 3):

As per DaveRandom's comment - you haven't actually made an instance of an Aclass object.

This works and displays data as expected:

```
<?php 
    $serverloc='serverURL';

    class Aclass{
        global $serverloc;      
        function Afunction()
        {
            echo  $serverloc;
        } 
    }

    $me = new Aclass();

    $me->Afunction(); // output: serverURL

?>
```

Edit: DaveRandom seems to post asnwers as comments. Go Vote up some of his other answers, the rep belongs to him not me. I am his ghostwriter tonight.

Comment: hej~ my real program actually is called by a form on other page and it call Afunction. After I press submit button, I can see other info I print out in Afunction, but not the $serverloc. I tried add global in from of it, it doesn't work still, but I found something weird in my program. please check my new update

Comment: @Jean Hey, I updated my answer. Try sticking the global inside the class, not the function. If that doesn't work, lets jump into a chat to see if we can work this out.

Comment: hi~the problem of this program's format is decided so I can't add new variables for the class. if I do, I got error msg for server.

Comment: If I excute the php file directly and instantiate the class and call the function, global varible work, but if I use the way that press submit button on other page to call this file. the global var stop working. as you see I am kinda new to PHP. I thought the class still instaniate if we use other form to call it ... but it seems not

Comment: @Jean You *always* need to make an instance of a class before you can call it's features - short of it's static's.

Comment: so you mean in my case the class didn't get instanitate. So what happen if a function in a class is called by a web page form like my case? Thank you for all the help

Answer (score 1):

If it is class globals you are after you could do like

```
class myClass
{    
  private $globVar = "myvariable";

  function myClass()
  {
    return $this->globVar;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> but when I run this class it didn't print anything out

You don't run [classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28computer_programming%29), in the sense of **executing** them. A class is a just a [data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure) that holds data and functions related (called methods).

As most traditional data structures, you create instances of them (called objects), and then you execute actions on them. One way to execute actions on objects (instances of classes), is to pass a message for it to do something: that is calling a method.

So, in your case you could do:

```
$obj = new Aclass(); // create an object, instance of Aclass
$obj->Afunction();   // ask it to perform an action (call a method)
```

Having said that, sometimes you want to create a class only for grouping related functions, that never actually really share data within an object. Often they may share data through a global variable (eg.: `$_SERVER`, `$_GET`, etc). That may be the case of your design right there.

Such classes can have its methods executed without never instantiating them, like this:

```
Aclass::Afunction();
```

While relying on global variables is usually an indicator of quick'n dirty design, there are cases in which it really is the best trade-off. I'd say that a `$serverlocation` or `$baseurl` may very well be one of these cases. :)

**See more:**

- [The basics on classes and objects in the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)
- [About the static keyword](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Comment: Yeah the global var I was trying to use here is for saving the base URL of the web site. I wrote a set of skeleton class and functions to test. and really made of a instance and call the function. It worked, but somehow it just doesn't work in the real program. I will update my question maybe you can give me some advice.